# I've got a fever

Tags: knowledge, rebus, music

Can you help me find my medicine?

[image: Career of Evil]

[image: One Step Ahead of the Devil]

[image: What is Quicksand]

[image: Burnin' for You]

[image: Eyes on Fire]

[image: Let Go]

[image: Lonely Teardrops]

---

The correct answer contains audible media, Bruce.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a list of songs by:

> Blue Oyster Cult

The list is:

> Blue Oyster Cult: Career of Evil
>  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HY3NQUoT89k

> BLUE OYSTER CULT - ONE STEP AHEAD OF THE DEVIL
>  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JvfQpPQXJMw

> Pre-Blue Öyster Cult - What Is Quicksand?
>  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NmuWoTk61fo

> Blue Oyster Cult: Burnin' For You
>  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ipqqEFoJPL4

> Blue Oyster Cult: Eyes On Fire
>  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GDZ10PRV8zs

> Blue Oyster Cult: Let Go
>  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zTtImX3hNaQ

> Blue Oyster Cult: Lonely Teardrops
>  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zQ6NOfLWjv8

Moving on, there is a related SNL Sketch ...

> https://vimeo.com/257364428

... where Bruce says :

> I've got a fever ...
>   ... the only prescription is :
>  "more cowbell"

> https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=i%20got%20a%20fever%20and%20the%20only%20prescription%20is%20more%20cowbell